# PhantomJS QUnit tests do not run on Jenkins CI server

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, phantomjs, automated-tests, qunit

### **Details on Jenkins project configuration**

Following [this tutorial](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_CI.html)

**Virtualenv Builder commands**

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py test lists accounts
pip install selenium
pip install fabric3
python manage.py tests functional_tests
```

**Execute Shell commands**

`phantomjs lists/static/tests/runner.js lists/static/tests/tests.html`

I obtained the latest `runner.js` file from [here](https://github.com/jonkemp/qunit-phantomjs-runner).

When I "Build Now" the Virtualenv commands run fine, but things go south when I get to the PhantomJS command:

```
*bunch of stuff saying everything has worked so far*

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 239.930s

OK
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
[Superlists] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3451109904869093293.sh
+ phantomjs lists/static/tests/runner.js lists/static/tests/tests.html
```

and it never completes. I think one time I started a build, forgot about it, and found out later it was still going after 6 days. Not sure why there isn't any output of some kind if the test is running.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but I'll chime in to say that phantomjs may not be the best route. I would suggest switching to headless Chrome. There's a number of [articles](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai) on it (although not specifically to your setup). Sorry I don't have a better answer for you

Comment: The real answer for OPs question is here: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_CI.html#comment-3576816956 and it's basically: runner.js was not the correct file. I think this question should rather be deleted because it's really misleading (although with best intentions by OP, this is not meant as an offense).